# jquery animate height, "from bottom to top", stop before top

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, navigation

I am trying to toggle a navigation container/div with jquery.

and i have the following code

style.css

```
#site-navigation {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 45px;
    left: 30px;
    right: 30px;
    top: 50px;
}
.main-nav-toggle {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    z-index: 100;
}
.main-nav-toggle .icon {
    background: gray;
    color: white;
    font-size: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 5px 10px;;
    line-height: 1;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

and home.html

```
<div id="site-nav-container">
    <div class="main-nav-toggle">
        <div class="toggle icon"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></div>
        <a href="#site-navigation" class="screen-reader-text">primary-menu</a>
    </div>
    <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
        <div class="menu-test-container">
            <ul id="primary-menu" class="menu">
                <li id="menu-item-1776" class="1776">
                    <a href="#">Level 1</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li id="menu-item-1778" class="item-1778">
                            <a href="#">Level 2a</a>
                            <ul class="sub-menu">
                                <li id="menu-item-1780" class="item-1780">
                                    <a href="#">Level 3a</a>
                                </li>
                                <li id="menu-item-1779" class="item-1779">
                                    <a href="#">Level 3b</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li id="menu-item-1777" class="item-1777">
                            <a href="#">Level 2b</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>                        
     </nav> <!--#site-navigation-->
</div>
```

main-toggle.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(".main-nav-toggle .icon").click(function(){
        $("#site-navigation").animate({height: 'toggle'}, 1000, function(){
            $('.main-nav-toggle').toggleClass('active');
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

which works almost as expected.

it should function such
so the container will be higher from the bottom up.
but still stops 50px from the top

img link: [what it should look like](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nh9ke226ih700zm/toggle.jpg?dl=0)

This is my first jquery code

please be nice

Comment: So you want the menu to animate up from the bottom when you press the button? If you animate the height it will animate downwards, not upwards. Can you make a fiddle or plunkr demonstrating the issue

Comment: here is a link to a live domain with the code [link](http://peterbuchhansen.info/) you will have to resize the width of the browser to below 480px to see the navigation bar function with the .js

but yes i want the menu to animate up from the bottom when i press the button 

i can work on a fiddle will take some time have not made one before

Comment: You don't need to make a fiddle now that I've seen the live example. Animating height is not enough to make this work. You will have to animate height as well as a top value to keep the menu in place. That way the menu will get smaller, but the bottom of it will stay in the same place. I will try to make a simple plunkr and post an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or, as an alternative, you could just let CSS handle everything by using the convenient `transition` property:
This renders / feels much nicer for me, since the browser doesn't take external instructions on a timer, but computes the steps itself, the best way it can.

(I also preserved your toggle button toggling the "active" class after the animation, however there were no rules for it in your CSS)

https://jsfiddle.net/svArtist/k293f6bj/

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(".main-nav-toggle .icon").click(function(){
        $("#site-navigation").toggleClass("open");
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('.main-nav-toggle').toggleClass('active');
        }, 1000);
        return false;
    });
});
```

```css
#site-navigation {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 10%;
    left: 10%;
    right: 10%;
    background-color:#eee;
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid #aaa;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    height:0%;
    opacity:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    transition: height 1s, opacity 1s;
}
#site-navigation.open {
  height: 80%;
  opacity:1;
}
.main-nav-toggle {
    position: fixed;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    z-index: 100;
}
.main-nav-toggle .icon {
    background: gray;
    color: white;
    font-size: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 5px 10px;;
    line-height: 1;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="site-nav-container">
    <div class="main-nav-toggle">
        <div class="toggle icon"><i class="fa fa-bars">TOGGLEME</i></div>
        <a href="#site-navigation" class="screen-reader-text">primary-menu</a>
    </div>
    <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
        <div class="menu-test-container">
            <ul id="primary-menu" class="menu">
                <li id="menu-item-1776" class="1776">
                    <a href="#">Level 1</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li id="menu-item-1778" class="item-1778">
                            <a href="#">Level 2a</a>
                            <ul class="sub-menu">
                                <li id="menu-item-1780" class="item-1780">
                                    <a href="#">Level 3a</a>
                                </li>
                                <li id="menu-item-1779" class="item-1779">
                                    <a href="#">Level 3b</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li id="menu-item-1777" class="item-1777">
                            <a href="#">Level 2b</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>                        
     </nav> <!--#site-navigation-->
</div>
```

Comment: i really think this is the one, but because css transition is not supporter in older browser i would really like to remove them, is that a possible? 

i really don´t need the opacity, and i have removed that but then i am left with the small closed container ?

Comment: tanks i found the solution with you help :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working plunkr of what I think you want: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZZyokGfziUD0jgVEGIXf

Basically as the menu is opening you need to move the offset as well to keep it positions at the bottom.

```
(function($){
  var $menu = $('.menu');
  var $button = $('.button');

  var openMenu = function(){
    $menu.data('open', true);

    $menu.animate({
      height: '400px',
      bottom: '50px'
    });
  };

  var closeMenu = function(){
    $menu.data('open', false);
    $menu.animate({
      height: 0,
      bottom: '50px'
    });
  }

  var animateMenu = function(){
    if($menu.data('open')){
      closeMenu();
    } else{
      openMenu();
    }
  };

  $button.on('click', animateMenu);
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Ben Philipp for finding the solution and other for there time

[jsfiddle][1]

https://jsfiddle.net/BugiBH/uk1j9cdw/

```
<div id="site-nav-container">
    <div class="main-nav-toggle">
        <div class="toggle icon"><i class="fa fa-bars">TOGGLEME</i></div>
        <a href="#site-navigation" class="screen-reader-text">primary-menu</a>
    </div>
    <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
        <div class="menu-test-container">
            <ul id="primary-menu" class="menu">
                <li id="menu-item-1776" class="1776">
                    <a href="#">Level 1</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li id="menu-item-1778" class="item-1778">
                            <a href="#">Level 2a</a>
                            <ul class="sub-menu">
                                <li id="menu-item-1780" class="item-1780">
                                    <a href="#">Level 3a</a>
                                </li>
                                <li id="menu-item-1779" class="item-1779">
                                    <a href="#">Level 3b</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li id="menu-item-1777" class="item-1777">
                            <a href="#">Level 2b</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>                        
     </nav> <!--#site-navigation-->
</div>

#site-navigation {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 10%;
    left: 10%;
    right: 10%;
    background-color:#eee;
    padding:0px;
    display : none;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    height:80%;
    overflow:hidden;
    border-top: 2px solid black;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

.main-nav-toggle {
    position: fixed;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    z-index: 100;
}
.main-nav-toggle .icon {
    background: gray;
    color: white;
    font-size: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 5px 10px;;
    line-height: 1;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
}



jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(".main-nav-toggle .icon").click(function(){
        $("#site-navigation").animate({height: 'toggle'}, function(){
            $('.main-nav-toggle').toggleClass('active');
        });
        // Optional return false to avoid the page "jumping" when clicked
        return false;
    });
});
```